# Using RequestToken for second time in twitter integration shows popup "You don't have access to appname"

Tags: android, twitter

Requesting access to token for second time doesn't work thats why we need to store the token for first time to use it in future reference.Thats what i am trying to do here in Twitter integration using SharedPreference while posting tweet.It works fine for the first time while posting tweet but shows popup in second time showing "You don't have access to appname.Please return to appname to continue signup process".

```
 private class TokenGet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
               if(requestTokenFirstTime) {
                   requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
                   oauth_url = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
                   //         requestTokenFirstTime = false;
                   //    }
                   SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();

                   edit.putString("Request_TOKEN", requestToken.getToken());
                   edit.putString("Request_TOKEN_SECRET", requestToken.getTokenSecret());
                   edit.putString("OAUTH_URLT", oauth_url);
                   edit.commit();
                   requestTokenFirstTime = false;
               }
                else {

                   requestToken = new RequestToken(pref.getString("Request_TOKEN", ""), pref.getString("Request_TOKEN_SECRET", ""));


                   oauth_url = pref.getString("OAUTH_URLT", "null");
               }

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return oauth_url;
        }
```

Below is my complete code for TwitterFragment.java
TwitterFragment.java

```
public class TwitterFragment extends ListFragment {
    final static String ScreenName = "IBL_Official";
    final static String LOG_TAG = "rnc";
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private ListFragment activity;
    private ListView listView;
    public static EditText tx1;
    private ProgressBar mDialog;
    private QuickReturnFrameLayout searchLayout;
Button login;
    boolean requestTokenFirstTime = true;
    twitter4j.Twitter twitter;
    RequestToken requestToken = null;
    //static RequestToken requestToken ;
    twitter4j.auth.AccessToken accessToken;
    String oauth_url,oauth_verifier,profile_url;
    Dialog auth_dialog;
    WebView web;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        }
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.activity = this;

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        downloadTweets();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twit_list, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        tx1=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.postcomment);
        mDialog = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        searchLayout = (QuickReturnFrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_layout);
        listView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        ((QuickReturnFrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_layout)).attach(listView);
        rootView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        login = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.postbutton);
        pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(pref.getString("CONSUMER_KEY", ""), pref.getString("CONSUMER_SECRET", ""));
        login.setOnClickListener(new LoginProcess());

        return rootView;
    }


    public void downloadTweets() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadTwitterTask().execute(ScreenName);
        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "No network connection available.");
        }
    }

    public class DownloadTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "AuSSA6AHeCv9gskRhGQjSymCO";
        final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "eyRoYBONVh45V185TBYbbb3i9BpWmmaiv4wLbBYXd7UcZGGaDw";
        final static String TwitterTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
        final static String TwitterStreamURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... screenNames) {
            String result = null;

            if (screenNames.length > 0) {
                result = getTwitterStream(screenNames[0]);
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            Twitte twits = jsonToTwitter(result);

            System.out.println(result);

            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> link = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();
            String logoimage = "";
            String name = "";
            String officialname = "";
            for (Tweet tweet : twits) {

                String[] splitted = tweet.getText().split("http://");
                Log.d("splitted", String.valueOf(splitted.length));
                data.add(splitted[0]);
                if (splitted.length > 1) {
                    link.add("http://" + splitted[1]);
                } else {
                    link.add("");
                }
                logoimage = tweet.getUser().getProfileImageUrl();
                name = tweet.getUser().getName();
                officialname = "@ " + tweet.getUser().getScreenName();
                time.add(tweet.getDateCreated());
            }
            //
            Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(logoimage);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                image = getRoundedShape(image);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("error in image", e.toString());
                Log.d("image", logoimage);
            }

            try {
                TwitterAdapter adapter = new TwitterAdapter(getActivity(), data, link, image, time, name, officialname);

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        }

        public Twitte jsonToTwitter(String result) {
            Twitte twits = null;
            if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    twits = gson.fromJson(result, Twitte.class);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {

                }
            }
            return twits;
        }

        public Authenticated jsonToAuthenticated(String rawAuthorization) {
            Authenticated auth = null;
            if (rawAuthorization != null && rawAuthorization.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    auth = gson.fromJson(rawAuthorization, Authenticated.class);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {

                }
            }
            return auth;
        }

        public String getResponseBody(HttpRequestBase request) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

                if (statusCode == 200) {

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                } else {
                    sb.append(reason);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            } catch (ClientProtocolException ex1) {
            } catch (IOException ex2) {
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String getTwitterStream(String screenName) {
            String results = null;

            try {

                String urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
                String urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");


                String combined = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;


                String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(combined.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TwitterTokenURL);
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Encoded);
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
                String rawAuthorization = getResponseBody(httpPost);
                Authenticated auth = jsonToAuthenticated(rawAuthorization);


                if (auth != null && auth.token_type.equals("bearer")) {


                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TwitterStreamURL + screenName);


                    httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.access_token);
                    httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                    results = getResponseBody(httpGet);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex1) {
            }
            return results;
        }

        public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
            int targetWidth = 50;
            int targetHeight = 50;
            Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
                    targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
            Path path = new Path();
            path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
                    ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
                    (Math.min(((float) targetWidth),
                            ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                    Path.Direction.CCW
            );

            canvas.clipPath(path);
            Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
            canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap,
                    new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                            sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
                    new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null
            );
            return targetBitmap;
        }
    }
    private class LoginProcess implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new TokenGet().execute();
        }}
    private class TokenGet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
               if(requestTokenFirstTime) {
                   requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
                   oauth_url = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
                   //         requestTokenFirstTime = false;
                   //    }
                   SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();

                   edit.putString("Request_TOKEN", requestToken.getToken());
                   edit.putString("Request_TOKEN_SECRET", requestToken.getTokenSecret());
                   edit.putString("OAUTH_URLT", oauth_url);
                   edit.commit();
                   requestTokenFirstTime = false;
               }
                else {

                   requestToken = new RequestToken(pref.getString("Request_TOKEN", ""), pref.getString("Request_TOKEN_SECRET", ""));


                   oauth_url = pref.getString("OAUTH_URLT", "null");
               }

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return oauth_url;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String oauth_url) {
            if(oauth_url != null){
                Log.e("URL", oauth_url);
                auth_dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                auth_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                auth_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.auth_dialog);
                web = (WebView)auth_dialog.findViewById(R.id.webv);
                web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                web.loadUrl(oauth_url);
                web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    boolean authComplete = false;
                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                        if (url.contains("oauth_verifier") && authComplete == false){
                            authComplete = true;
                            Log.e("Url",url);
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                            oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                            auth_dialog.dismiss();
                            new AccessTokenGet().execute();
                        }else if(url.contains("denied")){
                            auth_dialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry !, Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                auth_dialog.show();
                auth_dialog.setCancelable(true);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry !, Network Error or Invalid Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    private class AccessTokenGet extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progress.setMessage("Fetching Data ...");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {

                    accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                    edit.putString("ACCESS_TOKEN", accessToken.getToken());
                    edit.putString("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET", accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    User user = twitter.showUser(accessToken.getUserId());
                    profile_url = user.getOriginalProfileImageURL();

                    edit.putString("NAME", user.getName());
                    edit.putString("IMAGE_URL", user.getOriginalProfileImageURL());
                    edit.commit();

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean response) {
            if(response){
                progress.hide();
               // progress.dismiss();

                Fragment profile = new ProfileFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, profile);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
            else{

                auth_dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may simply want to hang on to the oauth access token after the first attempt (or ask for it by calling `twitter.getOAuthAccessToken()` ) and reuse it for the second time.

I ran into a similar experience and I found that the `twitter4j.Twitter twitter;` instance already had an access token associated with this instance from my first attempt. So when I asked for the authentication url from the request token  ( `oauth_url = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();` ) and opened it in a webpage I got a message similar to your problem description ( "You don't have access to  Please return to  to continue the signup process." ).

I think if you wanted to you could also start over by recreating the twitter4j.Twitter instance and the related instance variables (like the RequestToken ). However this would also require you to then do the whole authentication process again with would be repeating the same work you did on the first attempt.